# .ipa fails to install via Windows iTunes 12.3.2.35

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, itunes

I have my application's `.ipa` built with enterprise profile. I am able to install it through iTunes on my Mac but not through iTunes on Windows 7. It shows only "installing", it never gets installed. My iTunes version is the same for iMac and Windows 7 (12.3.2.35).

Comment: Check the device id for your windows device is added in dev center or not

Comment: Kindly check if the device is added to the profile that you used for generating the .ipa file.

Comment: The OP mentions an Enterprise profile, so there should be no need to register an UDID. Vikash, can you give details of your build / export process? Are you sure you are indeed using an Enterprise distribution profile (rather than a development profile, which would indeed be an issue if the device is not registered in the profile)?

Comment: @jcaron, if any think wrong to create ipa then it will not install through my iMac system also. but i am able to do through my iMac.

Comment: You're not telling us whether you're installing on the same device or different devices? If you're installing on different devices, the issue may be that you're using the development profile, and the device the install works on is registered on that profile, while the one it doesn't work on is not. If it's the same device, then there may be an issue with the iTunes install, the Windows version is quite flaky. Have you tried doing an over-the-air install (via a web server rather than iTunes)? Have you checked the device's logs?

Comment: The first installation of a App must be done by a device with MacOS. After it you can usually install with a Windows PC. I also never understood that. But always we release a version for testing we pre-installation with a Mac and then use Windows normally.

Comment: @jcaron, i tired with new device, who is not registered on my debug profile.i didn't tried with over-the-air.

Comment: @HaroldoGondim, i also observed same thing, once i installed through my mac, after that it will start working on windows also. But the same ipa is not woking for U.S guys. they are tried with mac os as well as windows also.

Comment: Most certainly your .ipa is not using the distribution provisioning profile but the development one. What procedure do you use to generate the .ipa? You must archive then export, save for enterprise deployment.

Comment: @jcaron, if i did wrong to create ipa then it will not installed to other phone also. just now i checked with one of my friend, who's UUID was not added to development profile. He is able to installed. 

yesterday i was tried to iPhone6 also, that UUID was also not added to my development profile.